# Wrap getter and setter with "operator[]"

Tags: c++, boost-propertytree

Many libraries provide us getter and setters to access and modify there processed variables. One of the libraries is `Boost PropertyTree`. I want to wrap getter and setter in `boost::property_tree::ptree` with `operator[]`.

**Source:**

```
class XMLDocument {
    boost::property_tree::ptree ptree_;

public:
    XMLDocument(const std::string &content) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        boost::property_tree::read_xml(ss << content, ptree_);
    }
    template <typename T> T &operator[](const std::string &path) { /* TODO */ }
}

int main() {
    XMLDocument xml("<foo>bar</foo><baz>qux</baz>");
    std::cout << xml["foo"] << std::endl; // Access the element.
    xml["baz"] = "quux"; // Modify the element.
    std::cout << xml["baz"] << std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
bar
quux
```

How can I do?

Comment: Just to be clear, this is demonstrative code, not compilable code ?

Comment: Your code relies on runtime info to give compile-time types. `template`s are not an option when you rely on runtime info.

Comment: @Quentin Yes. I didn't check whether the code throws syntax errors or not.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Hmm... Then, should I use `boost::any`s instead of it?

Comment: If you know all of the possible data you might get, just use some sort of polymorphism and throw some error if you get unexpected data. `boost::any` is more of a last resort.